# How to delete a hard link in a directory without write permissions?

Tags: linux, shell, file-permissions, rm, incremental-backup

I'm configuring a snapshot daily backup based on this recipe: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

To summarize, on the backup server I rotate the older copies by running:

```
dir=backup_directory
rm -rf ${dir}.3            # <-- this command reports "Permission denied" errors
mv     ${dir}.2 ${dir}.3
mv     ${dir}.1 ${dir}.2
cp -al ${dir}   ${dir}.1
```

And on the local server:

```
rsync --del -rvatlz local_directory_to_backup/ backup_server:backup_directory/. --exclude=".*" --ignore-errors
```

As `rsync` preserves permissions, it happens that some of the backedup directories don't have write permissions, and `rm -rf` fails to delete them.

I know I could run `chmod -R +w ${dir}.3` prior to `rm` but I wonder if there is a simpler way? I don't have access to `sudo` or root account on the backup server.

Comment: Similar question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/692630/how-to-delete-file-with-no-write-permissions-for-any-user?rq=1

Comment: @Moab yes, I've seen it. It suggests `chmod +w` is the only option. But it feels unsatisfying for 2 reasons: 1. it takes time, 2. as the backup snapshots contain (almost) all hard links, if I change permissions of the oldest snapshot, I change it for all of them. It's not end of the world, but doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: You can change the *group* ownership of a parent folder with *chown* or *chgrp* (https://linuxize.com/post/chgrp-command-in-linux/) so that all in the group have full access.

Comment: You can do the  `rm` as `sudo`, and there are [solutions](https://superuser.com/a/1493912/8672) to avoid specifying the root password in a script. Do you have root permissions?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This actually seem to be the solution. I realize directories are not hard links. Thank you!

Comment: @harrymc No, I don't have access to root permissions. Also it feels weird that I'd need root permissions to delete a file created from a user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Warnings

1. **The code in this answer can be more destructive than `rm -rf`.** I try to write good code but bugs happen. Forget my reputation, I'm just a random guy on the Internet. Assume the code will delete all files you can delete. Few ways to mitigate the risk:

   - test the code in a virtual machine;
   - create a new user account that can only hurt itself;
   - backup your important files to an external HDD, verify, then physically disconnect the HDD;
   - understand the code and only then decide if you want to use it ([tricky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)).
2. In the question you used `rm -rf ${dir}.3`. In many shells you should [double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). By leaving `${dir}` unquoted you may remove more than you intend.

---

#### Building a nuke

<sup>(Hello NSA. I knew you would come.)</sup>

`chmod -R` prior to `rm` is quite simple. You can simplify it further by hiding any complexity behind a shell function or a script. Develop it once and then just call its name whenever needed. The script can run `chmod` before `rm` unconditionally; or it can run `rm` in hope it succeeds, trying `chmod` + `rm` if the first `rm` fails.

I understand you don't want `chmod` to affect all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) because some of them may be linked also outside of the directory you want to remove. In other words: hardlinks may exist. Mode bits (permissions) of a file are stored in its inode, not in the directory entry (entries) pointing to the inode; therefore multiple entries (pathnames) leading to the same inode cannot be `chmod`ed independently. If you don't want to `chmod` files that are going to survive in other directories then you shouldn't `chmod -R` mindlessly. Your concern is justified.

When your problem occurs, it's always a directory you need to `chmod`. Linux does not allow hardlinks to directories, so `chmod`ding the troublesome directory should not affect anything more (and the directory is going to be removed anyway). If you could `chmod -R` directories only then the "`chmod` + `rm`" solution would be good.

See this question: [*Generalized `chmod` function differentiating between directories and files*](https://superuser.com/q/1630085/432690). In [my answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1630119/432690) you will find a shell function named `chmodx` designed to `chmod` files of certain types. Let's use it to solve your problem:

```sh
nuke() {
  [ "$#" = 0 ] && return 0
  chmodx d -R u+w -- "$@"
  rm -rf -- "$@"
}
```

Usage: `nuke foo ./bar /baz/qux`.

Notes:

- `--` after `rm` [will make it stop parsing options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618), but `--` after `chmodx` will not work this way. If you run `nuke -whatever` then `find` (inside `chmodx`) will misbehave. Therefore you should `nuke ./-whatever` instead. Down below I will show how to solve this problem.
- `rm -rf --` without other arguments does nothing. `chmodx d -R u+w --` without other arguments runs `find` without any starting point. Some implementations of `find` use `.` in such case. The line with `[ "$#" = 0 ]` makes `nuke` invoked without arguments a no-op, even if `chmodx d -R u+w --` wouldn't be a no-op.
- `chmodx` runs `chmod` for every directory. For `nuke` you can modify its code and insert `-perm` (see `man 1 find`) in the right place to only `chmod` directories that need to be `chmod`ded. Or you can abuse `chmodx` to inject `! -perm -u+w` like this:

  ```sh
  nuke() {
    [ "$#" = 0 ] && return 0
    chmodx d -R u+w -- -u+w -perm ! "$@"
    rm -rf -- "$@"
  }
  ```

  This variant checks and sets user's permissions only. Such approach seems right for your usage case.

Processing a directory tree (or trees) with `chmodx` and then processing the same tree(s) with `rm` seems suboptimal. If your `find` supports `-delete` ([it may not](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690)) then `find foo -delete` shouldn't be significantly slower than `rm -rf foo`, maybe except cases when e.g. `dir1/dir2/…/dirN/fileZ` cannot be deleted and yet `find` tries to delete `dirN` to `dir1`. Note (some implementations of) `rm` may know there is no point in trying to remove these directories.

*But* `find foo -delete` can be improved and do something if `-delete` fails. With `-execdir` (which your `find` may or may not support) a basic solution to your problem can be:

```sh
nuke() {
   find "$@" ! -delete -execdir chmod u+w . \; -delete
}
```

The main advantage is the directory trees are not processed twice. Additional processes (`chmod`) will be spawned only where they are needed. There are disadvantages:

1. If the first `-delete` fails then a message will be printed to stderr. You can suppress it with `2>/dev/null` but other (potentially useful) messages will also be suppressed. We could use `rm -f … 2>/dev/null` instead of `-delete` but [this requires a shell](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690). The shell and `rm` are additional processes we want to avoid.
2. `nuke -whatever` will confuse `find`. Use `nuke ./-whatever`.
3. The example with `dir1/dir2/…/dirN/fileZ` (above) still applies.
4. (Advantage or disadvantage) `nuke /foo/bar` will eventually try to delete `bar`. If the attempt fails then `chmod u+w` will work on `foo` which is *not* meant to be removed. You may or may not want to change the mode bits of `foo`. If you don't mind changing them then `chmod u+w` is way better than `chmod +w`. Note in the same situation the variant with `chmodx` will leave `foo` alone, therefore it may not delete `bar`.

I think you cannot easily build one `find` command that will `chmod` a directory only if it needs to be `chmod`ded and `-delete` files in it *later*. This is because `-delete` implies `-depth` and `-depth` means the content of a directory will be processed before the directory itself.

OK, so let's build our improved `nuke`:

```sh
nuke() (
   [ "$#" = 0 ] && exit 0
   err=0
   for p do
      case "$p" in
      -* )
         p="./$p"
      ;;
      esac
      2>/dev/null find "$p" ! -delete -execdir chmod u+w . \; -delete
      if [ -e "$p" ]; then
         >&2 printf '%s survived\n' "$p"
         err=1
      fi
   done
   exit "$err"
)
```

The function nukes its arguments one by one. It reports survivors to stderr. Paths starting with `-` are supported. Note `nuke /foo/bar` will `chmod … /foo` if needed.

The function uses a subshell for two reasons:

- to make all variables local;
- to allow `exit` instead of `return`, so you can paste the body of the function verbatim into a file and make a standalone script if you want to (the only thing to add is a shebang).

The shell code is portable (should work in `sh`). Non-portable things are `-delete` and `-execdir`.